# Definir steps_per_epoch está aumentando drasticamente o tempo de treinamento

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow, keras

Esta é minha função de treinamento:

```
model.fit(train_states, train_plays, epochs= numEpochs,
        validation_data = (test_states,test_plays),
        shuffle=True)
```

Quando não defino steps per epoch, obtenho isso:

```
Train on 78800 samples, validate on 33780 samples
Epoch 1/100

   32/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 6:37 - loss: 4.8805 - acc: 0.0000e+00
  640/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 4.1140 - acc: 0.0844     
 1280/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 16s - loss: 3.7132 - acc: 0.1172
 1920/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 3.5422 - acc: 0.1354
 2560/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 3.4102 - acc: 0.1582
 3200/78800 [>.............................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 3.3105 - acc: 0.1681
 3840/78800 [>.............................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 3.2102 - acc: 0.1867 
...
```

Mas quando preciso definir:

```
model.fit(train_states, train_plays, epochs= numEpochs,
        validation_data = (test_states,test_plays),
        steps_per_epoch=78800,
        validation_steps=33780,
        shuffle=True)
```

O tempo de treinamento pra cada época aumenta absurdamente, mesmo ainda sendo 78800:

```
Epoch 1/100

    1/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 35:39:24 - loss: 4.8044 - acc: 0.0172
    2/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 34:48:03 - loss: 4.7417 - acc: 0.0114
    3/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 34:04:17 - loss: 4.6801 - acc: 0.0369
    4/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 33:59:25 - loss: 4.6148 - acc: 0.0528
    5/78800 [..............................] - ETA: 33:47:50 - loss: 4.5438 - acc: 0.0622
```

e mesmo que eu defina batch_size, ele cotinua indo de um em um

Então preciso de ajuda para entender o que está acontecendo e qual seria a solução

Estou usando Keras

Este é o modelo, caso necessário:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(8, 4)),
        keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2):

O padrão (default) do `.fit` do [Keras](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) é:

- `batch_size`: se não especificado, assume 32;
- `steps_per_epoch`: número de samples (amostras) dividido pelo batch size.

No primeiro caso, ele faz `78800 amostras / 32 batch size`, ou seja, `2462 steps` com `32 batchs` por step.

Já no segundo caso, quando especificado `steps_per_epoch=78800`, o `batch_size` é ajustado para `1`. Isto faz com que o backpropagation ocorra muito mais vezes (uma vez para cada step), aumentando o tempo de treinamento.

Note que em ambos os casos, o número de amostras de treino continua 78800.

Quando eu tento definir tanto `steps_per_epoch` quanto `batch_size`, acontece o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: If steps_per_epoch is set, the `batch_size` must be None.

Ou seja, não consigo especificar os dois ao mesmo tempo.